# date calcutation in excel based on other dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date

```
          =TODAY    
date A    date B    date C
```

I need formula which will calculate me date B.
I.e. If between date A and =TODAY has passed more then a year and if date C is empty then date B will be same as =TODAY, otherwise date be will same as date A plus one year.

I've managed to create formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(DATEDIF(date A,$date $B,"Y") >= 1, ISBLANK(date C)), TODAY(), DATE(YEAR(date A)+1,MONTH(date A),DAY(date A)))
```

but this doesn't seem to work when difference between date A and TODAY is more then one year.

Comment: "but this doesn't seem to work when..." - what exactly the issue? please post some sample data / screenshots. `ISBLANK(date C))` - do you have really blank cells, or cells with formulas appearing blank? `date C=""` is more safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I am in the UK so my answer uses dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy**

Let's say:
`date a` is in cell `A1`
`date b` is in cell `B1`, and
 
`date c` is in cell `C1`

Let's then say you put `31/02/2015` into cell `A1` and put `=IF(AND(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")>=1,ISBLANK(C1)),TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))` into cell `A2` the formula works for me.

As @Máté Juhász said in the comments, the problem arises when you have something in cell `C1`.  If that is the case, it will add 1 year to the date in A1 making it 31/02/2016 instead of today's date of 02/09/2016.

Cell `C1` can appear blank to you if you put a space into it, but Excel will see the space as data. So for safety, if you want to check a cell is humanly visible as blank by including a space as blank, you need to change the logical test to `=OR(ISBLANK(C1),C1=" ")` making the final formula in cell `B1` as `=IF(AND(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")>=1,OR(ISBLANK(C1),C1=" ")),TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))`

An alternative to `=OR(ISBLANK(C1),C1=" ")`, which has no functional difference except reducing the length of the formula by 6 characters, is by using the alternative suggested in the comment, which would be `=OR(C1="",C1=" ")` making an alternative final formula in cell `B1` as `=IF(AND(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")>=1,OR(C1="",C1=" ")),TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))`